# How do I bind a shared datasource to a shared dataset while deploying through PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, reporting-services

I have a PowerShell script to facilitate SSRS deployments. The script deploys shared data sources, shared data sets, and report definitions, and binds the shared data sources and data sets to the reports. The problem I have is that the shared data sets end up on the server without being bound to the data sources. In browsing the data set object in PS, I don't really see where I can programmatically bind it to a data source, though this binding can be done through the Report Manager interface

Below is the code that I use to create the data sets.

```
    if (Test-Path ($SourceDirectory.FullName + "\bin\debug"))
{
    foreach($rsdfile in Get-ChildItem ($SourceDirectory.FullName + "\bin\debug") -Filter *.rsd)
    {
        try
        {
            Write-host ""

            $rsdf = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($rsdfile)
            $RsdPath = $SourceDirectory.FullName+'\bin\debug\'+$rsdf+'.rsd'

            Write-Verbose "New-SSRSDataSet -RsdPath $RsdPath -Folder $DataSet_Folder"

            $RawDefinition = Get-Content -Encoding Byte -Path $RsdPath
            $warnings = $null

            $Results = $ssrsProxy.CreateCatalogItem("DataSet", $rsdf, $dataSetFolder_Final, $IsOverwriteDataSet, $RawDefinition, $null, [ref]$warnings)
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Host $msg
        }

    }
}
```